# .save() with save pre hook won't work with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, bcrypt

So I have been struggling with this for the last couple of days.

I created a User schema in Mongoose, and I have a pre save hook that hashes it's password field. Every time i tried to save a user to the database, i noticed the save method was never invoked. The error message that I got made no sense to me (at the time). Turns out, it had nothing to do with the pre save hook, and everything to do with the schema itself.

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    fullName: {
      type: String,
      maxlength: 50
    },
    about: {
      type: String,
      maxlength: 500
    },
    gender: {
      type: String,
    },
    dob: {
      type: String,
    },
    school: {
      type: String,
    },
    grade: {
      type: String,
      maxlength: 50
    },
    profilePicture: {
      type: String,
    },
    resume: {
      type: String,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      maxlength: 50
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      minlength: 6
    },
    favoriteJobs: {
      type: Array,
      default: []
    },
    followedPost: {
    type: Array,
    default: []
    },
    posts: {
    type: Array,
    default: []
    },
    eventsGoing: {
    type: Array,
    default: []
    },
    studentChat: {
    type: Array,
    default: [StudentChatSchema]
    },
    mentorChat: {
    type: Array,
    default: []
    },
    notifications: {
    type: Array,
    default: []
    },
})
```

Pre Save:

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next){
  var user = this;
  if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();

  bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
    if (err) return next(err);

    bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
      if (err) return next(err);
      if(hash) {
        user.password = hash;
        this.password = user.password;
        console.log('Password Hashed');
        console.log(user.password);
        return next();
      }
    })
  })
  })
```

Error:

```
Error: key $isUnderneathDocArray must not start with '$'
    at serializeInto (/Users/ferro/Desktop/United-Way/Express/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:911:19)
    at serializeObject (/Users/ferro/Desktop/United-Way/Express/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:347:18)
    at serializeInto (/Users/ferro/Desktop/United-Way/Express/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:937:17)
    at serializeObject (/Users/ferro/Desktop/United-Way/Express/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:347:18)
    at serializeInto (/Users/ferro/Desktop/United-Way/Express/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:937:17)
    at serializeObject (/Users/ferro/Desktop/United-Way/Express/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:347:18)
    at serializeInto (/Users/ferro/Desktop/United-Way/Express/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:727:17)
    at serializeObject (/Users/ferro/Desktop/United-Way/Express/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:347:18)
    at serializeInto (/Users/ferro/Desktop/United-Way/Express/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:937:17)
    at serializeObject (/Users/ferro/Desktop/United-Way/Express/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:347:18)
    at serializeInto (/Users/ferro/Desktop/United-Way/Express/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:937:17)
    at serializeObject (/Users/ferro/Desktop/United-Way/Express/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:347:18)
    at serializeInto (/Users/ferro/Desktop/United-Way/Express/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:937:17)
    at serializeObject (/Users/ferro/Desktop/United-Way/Express/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:347:18)
    at serializeInto (/Users/ferro/Desktop/United-Way/Express/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:727:17)
    at serializeObject (/Users/ferro/Desktop/United-Way/Express/node_modules/bson/lib/bson/parser/serializer.js:347:18)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was here:

```
    studentChat: {
    type: Array,
    default: [StudentChatSchema]
    },
```

to

```
    studentChat: {
    type: Array,
    default: []
    },
```

Can't give an array a type of "Schema". Duh. I couldn't find this error message anywhere else so hopefully this helps someone else out.